# Using multiple secondary displays as a separated chrome/edge kiosk

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, kiosk

Using a computer with several secondary small screens,

Is there a way to enable Chrome\Edge Kiosk mode for a specific URL,

Each display (except the main one) has a separate profile and full-screen mode.

I prefer to turn off the secondary display while the kiosk is not running.

Comment: You can just make the Browser in full screen by pressing F11 (keyboard shortcut may vary depending on browser) on one of the screens, and you should be able to continue using the computer while one of the screens has the Browser up in full screen.